# Rails - Problems refactoring controller's nested attribute creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, refactoring

I have models:

```
Transaction has_many :credits, :debits
Credit belongs_to :transaction
Debit belongs_to :transaction
```

Each credit must have a balancing debit and vice versa.

I currently (successfully) achieve this with the following inside Transaction's create method:

```
@transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction])

Transaction.transaction  do

  # Balance debits with credits (Sales)
  if params[:balance_transaction] == 'credit'
    @transaction.credits.each do |credit|
      @transaction.debits.push(Debit.new({
        :quantity => 0,
        :cost_per_unit => 0,
        :description => 'Balancing Debit',
        :amount => credit.amount,
        :account_id => 23 #Get from settings in future to allow users to choose Debtor account
      }))
    end
  elsif params[:balance_transaction] == 'debit'
    @transaction.debits.each do |debit|
      @transaction.credits.push(Credit.new({
        :quantity => 0,
        :cost_per_unit => 0,
        :description => 'Balancing Credit',
        :amount => credit.amount,
        :account_id => 43 #Get from settings in future to allow users to choose Creditor account
      }))
    end
  else
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # There's no balancing transaction. Don't save it!
  end

end
```

I tried moving the balancing debit/credit creation into the debit/credit models by replacing `@transactions.credits.push(...) with debit.balancing_credit` and putting the following in the debit model:

```
def balancing_credit
  transaction.credits.new({
    :quantity => 0,
    :cost_per_unit => 0,
    :description => 'Balancing Debit',
    :amount => amount,
    :account_id => 43 #Get from settings in future to allow users to choose Creditor account
  })
end
```

I thought this was pretty straightforward refactoring, but it throws up an `undefined method 'debits' for nil:NilClass` error. Seems it looks in the database for the not yet saved transaction in order to create the balancing credit? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the fact that such a mechanism should belong to the models, not to a controller. You could have a before_save callback on your Transaction model:

```
class Transaction
  after_save :balance_operations

  def balance_operations
    if credits
      credits.each do|credit|
        debit = debits.build (#do all your stuff here. build() automaticly fills the transaction_id field of your new debit with the proper id)
        return false unless debit.save
      end
    if debits # can use elsif if mutually exclusive conditions
      # same thing as above
    end
  end
 end
```

This relies on the fact that the callback chain is wrapped in an ActiveRecord::Base.transaction. If a callback returns false, ActiveRecord will perform a Rollback. See the "transaction" chapter **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks)** for more info.

If you have many operations in one transaction, you can also peek [a look at this to improve performance](http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/11/efficient-updates-data-import-in-rails/).

**Edit:** you can also add `validates_associated :debit, :credits` to your model

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked beautifully.

Also checked out that link about improving performance (yes, I'm using pgsql transactionally). Didn't know about that gem, interesting stuff. Cheers.

Comment: After further testing, found it was not saving the balancing debit/credit under the transaction as it should have been. Was leaving transaction_id blank. Changed it to an `after_save`, made the second `if` an `elsif` and used `debits.new` instead of `Debit.new`. Works correctly now, and the whole thing is wrapped in a transaction anyway so the COMMIT call is not until after the after_save.

Comment: my bad. i always think those things upside down. You're right, obviously your associated debits and credits cannot properly refer to a Transaction that is not saved, and as such has no ID. edited the answer to match this... please note the slight changes in syntax. thanks for feedback.